# Transfer multiple files using Bluetooth(BluetoothShare.java) in android

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, transfer

I am using the below code to transfer a file using Bluetooth without user interaction,
How can I transfer multiple files using this `BluetoothShare.java` :

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/test.mp3";
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)).toString());
values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, device.getAddress());
values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
Uri contentUri = getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: Have the same use case..can some one please guide..